# Convert odds ratio of unit change to whole range

Tags: r, regression

I try to do a logistic regression in R and then calculate an odds ratio. I have two groups of people, the first one more strongly exposed to a pollutant than the second one, and the first one developing a certain disease more often. 
I just use a set of toy data here. It's easy to generate a model and estimate the significance of influence of the pollutant exposure on developing the disease:

```
df <- data.frame(disease = as.factor(c(rep(1,100),rep(0,500))),
                 exposure=c(rnorm(100, mean = 200, sd = 50),
                    rnorm(500, mean = 100, sd = 20)))
model <- glm(formula = disease ~ exposure, data=df, 
              family = binomial(link = "logit"))
summary <-summary(model)
OR <- exp(cbind(OddRatio = coef(model), confint(model)))
```

In R, odds ratios are based on one unit change of the independent variable, e.g. changing the pollutant concentration for 1 mg/ml yields an odds ratio of around 1.1 to 1 in the example.

My question is now, how can I recalculate an odds ratio based on a change for several unit changes?  (across the whole range of pollutant exposure)

My first guess was the OR of the new range is OR of one unit change to the power of range size in units.

```
range <- max(df$exposure)-min(df$exposure)
ORRange <- (OR["exposure",1])^range
```

In the toy data, the range is about 300. And 1.1 ^ 300 is about  2x10^13, which is quite a lot.

Is this calculation correct, or must it be multiplied (1.1 x 300)? 
And what is the mathematical basis to prove the calculation?

Comment: Change the `formula` to, for example, `disease ~ I(exposure / range)`

Comment: Thanks, that looks elegant and intuitive. Above all, it yields same results as the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how you calculate an odds ratio for different units of change. First, multiply the coefficient on the logit scale (which is what R reports), and *then* use the `exp` function on it. Here is an example of calculating the odds ratio for 1, 2, and 3 units of change

```
unit.change = c(1,2,3)
exp(coef(model)["exposure"]*unit.change)
```

Comment: Are they not equivalent using exponential ruiles `all.equal(exp(coef(model)["exposure"]*unit.change), (OR["exposure",1])^unit.change)`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you're right, they are equivalent if you take the power.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, `exp(3*7) == exp(3)^7` does not yield `TRUE` in R, though it should. I guess it's a rounding error. The displayed numbers are the same (`1318815734`) but the internal ones deviate for some far decimal places.

Comment: So the "range OR" is calculated as I thought. But any idea why the calculation is allowed/mathematically correct? Or is it just intuition? If it were probabilites instead of OR I would believe `xyz^unit.change` is the way to go without a doubt...

Comment: @KonradG; for your first comment, yes its a rounding issue `all.equal(exp(3*7), exp(3)^7)`. For your second, its due to exponential rules: on the OR scale for a one unit increase in predictor the OR will increase multuplicatively by exp(\beta_{1}). For a two unit increase this will increase by exp(2*\beta_{1}) which equals exp(\beta_{1})^2.